# Finding unique 9 digit numbers

Tags: python, iteration

I'm writing a program that accepts as input a 9 digit number with each number from 1-9 (i.e 459876231) The program takes that number and then finds the next highest number with the same digits. The code I have works, but only when I put the print statement within the for loop.

```
n = int(input("Please input a 9 digit number"))

n_str = str(n)  
n_str1 = str(n+1)

while n < 1000000000:

    for char in n_str:
        if not char in n_str1:
            n += 1
            n_str1 = str(n)
            print(n)
```

If I put don't indent the print statement to where it is now, the program will not work. Putting the print statement here also displays every number that the program tries on the way to the correct number, and I only want to display the final answer. Why is this happening? I've tried storing n in a completely new variable and then trying to print outside the loop but get the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean by, "the program will not work"? Errors? Incorrect output? No output? Something else?

Comment: what will the expected output be from 459876231?

Comment: Your code does not output the highest number. But you say it works.

Comment: the program gets stuck in the while loop. i need a condition that breaks it out once it reaches the correct number. the output for 459876231 is 459876312

Answer (score 1):

It's because if you do `n += 1`, `n` will be 1, then 2, 3.., so you need to print `n` every time. If you print `n` outside of the `for`, it will only print its last value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fixed like:

```py
n = int(input("Please input a 9 digit number: "))
n_str = str(n)  
n_str1 = str(n+1)

while n < 1000000000:
    found = True
    for char in n_str:
        if not char in n_str1:
            n += 1
            n_str1 = str(n)
            found = False
            break

    if found:
        print(n)
        break
```

There is a bug in your condition

```py
    for char in n_str:
        if not char in n_str1:
```

If input number is `333222323`, `n_str1` is `333222324`, digit check `char in n_str1` would be all true and `333222323` would be the result.

I find the LeetCode problem [31. Next Permutation](https://leetcode.com/problems/next-permutation/) is quite similar to your question, and there are already many recommended solutions, most are more efficient than yours.

This example code is based on my LeetCode answer:

```py
nstr = input("Please input a 9 digit number: ")
nums = [int(c) for c in nstr]

l = len(nums) # length should be 9

for i in range(l-2, -1, -1):
    swap_idx, swap_n = None, None
    for j in range(i+1, l):
        if (nums[i] < nums[j]) and (not swap_n or (nums[j] < swap_n)):
            swap_idx, swap_n = j, nums[j]

    if swap_idx:
        tmp = nums[i]
        nums[i] = nums[swap_idx]
        nums[swap_idx] = tmp
        break

nums = nums[:i+1] + sorted(nums[i+1:])
print(''.join([str(i) for i in nums]))
```

With a test:

```
Please input a 9 digit number: 459876231
459876312

Please input a 9 digit number: 333222323
333222332
```